# python IDLE fibonocci sequence my model doesn't work

Tags: python

need help with this, i tried something but it didn't work for some reason. I need some help to figure it out.

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return F(n-1)+F(n-2)
F('3')
```

and here is the original problem- Write a function called fib which takes as a parameter an integer, n, and returns the nth number in the Fibonocci sequence (see definition below). If n is zero or a negative number, your function should return an error message in the form of a string "Error: Invalid input.".

The Fibonocci sequence is `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...` where the first two numbers are 1, and each number beyond that is calculated as the sum of the previous two numbers (2 = 1+1, 3 = 2+1, 5 = 3+2, 8=5+3, etc).

Comment: please add the error message

Comment: btw, your function does not called "fib" and does not return an error for zero or negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for the invalid numbers error you are supposed to print out, I would suggest adding another if statement in.  Below shows an example of how you could set any negative number to return an error message.

```
    if n < 0: return "Error: Invalid Input"
```

For the F function, it goes back to data types.  When you put in quotes around something, that specifies an actual string. When you just have a number, it will be an integer data type. For this, we want an integer data type since we want to do math operations on our number. This is why you should remove the quotes.

Comment: i added it, put i get this as result Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/fibonacci.py", line 9, in <module>
    F('3')
  File "C:/Python34/fibonacci.py", line 6, in F
    elif n<0:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: @ivakukovska Make sure you have removed the quotes around the 3 when you are calling the function.

Comment: thank you, but i am still not getting the outcome i want

Comment: What outcome is happening? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: ahhh... i am tired, i will try tomorrow, but thanks for all the help,all the information you gave me was very very useful, Thanks again

Comment: @ivakukovska Happy to help. Also, http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python provides an excellent tutorial for learning Python that I definitely recommend. That was how I started learning.

Answer (score 2):

i guess the problem is that you use string instead of integer.
try `F(3)` instead of `F('3')`

or give more information about the error you get

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fib(x, t1=0, t2=1):
    if x == 0:
        return "Invalid"
    if x == 1:
        if t1 != 0:
            return t1
        return 0
    else:
        return "{}  {}".format(t1, fib(x - 1, t2, (t1 + t2)))

print(fib(0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).